# Poisson distribution problem: probability of getting at least 2 e-mails

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to solve the **problem:**

> *Given that an corporation gets usually 360 e-mails in each 6 hours of work what is the probability that in 10 minutes the corporation will get at least 2 e-mails?*

The problem asks to model that question using Poisson probability distribution ($x\in \mathbb{N}$)

$$P(x) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Then I tried to find lambda. I think lambda should be the mean value of e-mails that the corporation receives so $\lambda = 1$; this is the number of e-mails per minute of work. Now we get that the probability that at least two e mails are get it is the sum of probabilities up to $x=2$:

$$P(0)+P(1)+P(2) = e^{-1}+e^{-1}+e^{-1}/2 = 5e^{-1}/2 = 0,91969$$

This makes sense because the probability must be very high. But it is not the correct answer given by the professor: $0,9995$.

> *Where I'm wrong?*
>
> *Was my approach to the problem correct?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability of *at least two* is the probability of receiving two, or three, or four, etc. You computed the probability of *at most* two.

Now, you can do it as $$P(X\geq2)=P(X=2)+P(X=3)+\dots=\sum_{x=2}^\infty P(X=x),$$

and compute the infinite sum, or do it by finding the complementary event of "at least 2", which is "at most one":

$$P(X\geq2)=1-P(X<2)=1-P(X\leq1)=1-[P(X=0)+P(X=1)].$$

You found the correct rate, $\lambda=1$ messages/minute. But you are asked about a 10 minute period. For any Poisson process, the number of arrivals in a period $[0,t]$ has the following probability:
$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^x}{x!}.$$

So in your case, with $t=10$ and $\lambda=1$,
$$P(X=0)=\frac{e^{-10}(10)^0}{0!}=e^{-10}=0.00004539992,$$
$$P(X=1)=\frac{e^{-10}(10)^1}{1!}=10e^{-10}=0.00045399929.$$

So $$P(X\geq2)=1-0.00004539992-0.00045399929=0.99950060077.$$

Comment: Awsome answer! Very instructive! Thank's

Comment: Hi! Can you maybe help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598781/poisson-probability-per-week Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors.

Your $\lambda$ is wrong.  The expected rate of one per minute is correct, but we have a run of ten minutes, so the expected number is ten.

Your computation adding the values for $0,1,2$ computes the chance that the corporation will get (in your model) at most $2$ e-mails, not at least $2$ e-mails.  You should add the probabilities for $0$ and $1$, then subtract the sum from $1$ to get the chance of at least two.

Comment: Hi! Can you maybe help me with this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598781/poisson-probability-per-week